# Table with two buttons. One jQuery-ajax doesn't replace <tbody> of <table>, but instead redirects browser to ajax url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

**EDIT: I originally simplified my code, hoping to isolate my problem, but I see I need to show the unsimplified code to discover my problem; so I'm replacing the HTML and JavaScript with the "full version", and have edited my description to include new information.**

I have a table with two Buttons.

One button works fine: it triggers a jQuery overlay form so the user can enter data for a new row. AJAX then removes the "old" < tbody > and replaces it with a new < tbody > (with the new row added).  That works fine. --critically, it also stores the new row into a database.

The other button is responsible for removing rows that have been checked by the user.  jQuery AJAX **does** remove the selected rows from the database, but instead of replacing the "old" < tbody > with the new (now smaller) one, it loads the AJAX url into the browser, which shows the raw new set of rows that were intended to be put into the < tbody >. Using the back button and F5-ing shows that the rows were indeed removed.

I don't know how to 'blend' these buttons into one table.

Here is the jQuery:

```
    // opens a pop-up form as an overlay (id: #box_form) that has its own buttons
$('#addy').click(function(e){   
    //e.preventDefault();
    $('#box_form').dialog('open');
});

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(
        {altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"}
);

$('#box_form').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 340,
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Cancel",
            click: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        {
            text: "Submit",
            click: function() {
                var symbol = $("#symbol").val();
                var quant = $("#quant").val();
                var price = $("#price").val();
                var datepicker = $("#datepicker").val();
                var fee = $("#fee").val();
                var account = $("#account").val();
                var owner = $("#owner").val();
                // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
                var dataString = 'symbol='+ symbol + '&quant='+ quant + '&price='+ price + '&datepicker='+ datepicker + '&fee='+ fee + '&account='+ account + '&owner='+ owner;
                if(symbol==''||quant==''||price==''||datepicker==''||fee==''||account=='')
                {
                    alert("Please Fill All Fields");
                }
                else
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "addPurch.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(result){
                            //document.getElementById("stocktablebody").innerHTML = result;
                            $("#stockstable tbody").html(result);
                        }
                    });
                    //close this little input form overlay
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    ]
});

$('#selectAll').click(function(event){  
    $(this).closest('table').find('td input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});

$('#removie').submit(function(event){   
    event.preventDefault();
    var remove = $("#remove[]").val();
    var owner = $("#owner").val();
    var dataString = 'remove='+ remove + '&owner='+ owner;              
    //var url = "removePurch.php"; //$(this).attr('action');// this attribute's action (specified in <form> tag)

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "removePurch.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
            //document.getElementById("stocktablebody").innerHTML = result;
            $("#stockstable tbody").html(result);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Here is the HTML:
(First big div is for the Add button's jQuery pop-up; Second big block is the actual table.)

```
    <!-- Pop-up form hidden by JavaScript until button is clicked -->
<div id="box_form" title="Add a purchase">
    <form id="addsymbol" action="addPurch.php" method="POST"
        name="addstock" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="owner" id="owner" value="me" />
        <table class="popuptable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td class="right"><label for="symbol">Symbol:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="symbol" id="symbol"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="right">
                        <!--  for="..." Specifies which form element a label is bound to -->
                        <label for="quant">Quantity:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="quant" id="quant"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="right"><label for="price">Price for each: </label>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="price" id="price"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="right"><label for="fee">Fee: </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="fee" id="fee"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="right"><label for="datepicker">Date
                            Purchased: </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker">
                        <!-- had real trouble getting data to POST, just made all names,ids === and it worked -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="right"><label for="account">Which account:
                    </label></td>
                    <td><select name="account" id="account">
                            <option value="note">must fix fee functionality</option>
                            <option value="FidelityIndividual">Fidelity Individual</option>
                            <option value="FidelitySEP">Fidelity SEP</option>
                            <option value="FidelityRoth">Fidelity Roth</option>
                            <option value="ScottradeIRA">Scottrade IRA</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>

<!-- Table with two buttons (Add-a-row and Remove-a-row), and a checkbox for each row, and a checkbox to "check all rows" -->
<table id="stockstable" class="center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                <!--  this just triggers form to come up.  Form has its own buttons -->
                <input type="submit" id="addy" value="Add a stock purchase">
            </th>
            <th colspan="3">Activity Today</th>
            <th colspan="2">Change Since Purchase</th>
            <th colspan="3">Cost Basis</th>
            <th colspan="3">Purchas Details</th>
            <form action="removePurch.php" method="post"
                enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="hidden" name="owner" id="owner" value="me" />
                <th><button id="removie">Remove</button></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Symbol</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>$ change</th>
            <th>% change</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Purchase Price</th>
            <th>Total Cost</th>
            <th>Total % Change</th>
            <th>Total $ Change</th>
            <th>Fee</th>
            <th>Account</th>
            <th>Purchase Date</th>
            <th><input type="checkbox" name="remove[]" id="selectAll"
                value="all"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>International Business Machines</td>
                <td>ibm</td>
                <td>166.95</td>
                <td>+3.10</td>
                <td>1.86</td>
                <td>1,986.88%</td>
                <td>$158.95</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>71.00</td>
                <td>7.00</td>
                <td>note</td>
                <td>07/16/2015</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="remove[]"
                    value="55a3436f5490c4ed4cbbe1a5"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Facebook, Inc.</td>
                <td>fb</td>
                <td>87.95</td>
                <td>+2.07</td>
                <td>2.35</td>
                <td>999.38%</td>
                <td>$79.95</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>71.00</td>
                <td>7.00</td>
                <td>note</td>
                <td>07/30/2015</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="remove[]"
                    value="55a346745490c4ee4cbbe1a6"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </form>
</table>
```

Comment: You want to reload the only table area ? or the whole page after ajax successfully remove the row ?

Comment: `$("#remove[]").val()` - There is no element with id `remove[]` in the posted markup

Comment: Since the problem exists in the brower, not in the server, I'd rather post the (relevant part of) produced HTML instead of any PHP code.

Comment: Shah Rukh: "3) replace the old set of rows in < tbody > with the new set of rows."  I do not want to reload the entire page.  I do not want to reload even the < thead >.  I only want to reload the < tbody >.

Comment: Kos: I replaced the PHP (which generates the HTML) with HTML from View Source of browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't need the < form > tag in the table at all because JS has access to all the elements in the DOM.
2. in $('#removie').click(function(event) (I changed it from submit to click because it's no longer a form, but just a button), the checkboxes have to be "unpacked" or "discovered" by JavaScript, and put into a JavaScript array like so:

   ```
   var remove = [];
   $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
       remove[i] = $(this).val();
   });
   ```

...it somehow knows which checkboxes, even though I removed the < form > tag. 
The rest in that jQuery function is the same as the original question.

3. In the PHP, the checkbox data is received via POST only as a comma separated value, and has to be exploded into an array (oh, or not, depending on your code, really) like so:

   ```
   $remove = explode(',', $_POST['remove']);
   ```
4. Profit.